# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in Xcode after Firebase update

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebaseui

I updated FirebaseUI to the newest version, and that updated TwitterCore 3.0.0 (was 2.8.0), ever since I get this compiler error in Xcode:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_TWTRIdentifierForAdvertising", referenced from:
      +[TWTRCardConfiguration deviceID] in TwitterKit(TWTRCardConfiguration.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I currently reverted back to the previous version of TwitterCore even though it wasn't explicitly written in my Podfile. I wrote `pod 'TwitterCore', '~>2.8.0'`

Answer (score 9):

I have fixed TwitterCore >3.0.0 is problem for FirebaseUI > 3.0.0 or update pod

```
pod 'FirebaseUI'
pod 'TwitterCore', '<=2.8.0' # fixed
```

Good luck

Answer (score 5):

I noticed in the Firebase DatabaseExample podfile included with quickstart-ios that 'FirebaseUI' was renamed 'FirebaseUI/Database'.
I added it to the podfile with the correct name and all appears to be ok.

Comment: This worked for me too. Using just the `FirebaseUI/Database` pod resolved the linker error.

Answer (score 3):

If you are still struggling with this error then here you go my solution. I noticed that some of above solutions don't fix the problem with Twitter package as they just remove reference to it which is not a correct approach for those people who want to deal with Twitter feature.

At the moment, `FirebaseUI` version is `4.1.1` and `TwitterKit` >= `2.4` satisfies its requirements but according to my test the latest 2.* version (which is now 2.8.1) generate error with undefined symbol reference.

I checked out that `FirebaseUI` 4.1.1 works just fine with earlier `TwitterKit` 2.7. So my solution is to just force te cocoapod to install this version.

**Follow along the procedure:**

**1)** Add these two instances to your Podfile. (you can add selectively the subspecs of FirebaseUI if you don't want to install them all).

```
pod 'TwitterKit' , '2.7' 

pod 'FirebaseUI', '~> 4.0'
```

**2)** Run:

```
pod update
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it by using:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'app name' do

#pod 'FirebaseUI'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'

post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
end
end
end
end
```

So as you can see, I have commented `FirebaseUI` and used `FirebaseUI/Database` for database and `Firebase/Storage` for storage.

Answer (score 0):

This would be an example of how to define the podfile version.

Exemple:

target 'Your_project' do

```
pod 'Firebase', '~> 1.0'
```

end

Comment: I know, but some pods include inside of them other dependencies and pods. I added "pod 'TwitterCore', '~>2.8.0'" even though I didn't write it in the Podfile in the first place

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was just commented out this :

`#  pod 'FirebaseUI/Twitter'`

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 9, Swift 3, Firebase

-> _TWTRIdentifierForAdvertising", referenced

Thats help me:

first add in your Podfile:
pod 'FirebaseUI'**, '~> 4.0'**

after:
pod update

Answer (score 0):

If you use it pod in **testing**. You must add pod in MyAppTests target.

for example:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'TwitterCore', '~>3.0.0'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

    pod 'TwitterCore', '~>3.0.0'

  end

end
```