# FirebaseUI Auth Clang Error with TwitterKit

Tags: swift, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error and can't figure out what is going on. I am using Firebase4 for AuthUI. It is the one pulling in an older version of TwitterKit. Could this be the problem?

Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_TWTRIdentifierForAdvertising", referenced from:
      +[TWTRCardConfiguration deviceID] in TwitterKit(TWTRCardConfiguration.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: same as this posting. So click here instead.: [is answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188112/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-in-xcode-after-firebase-update)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your podfile to:

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'FirebaseInstanceID'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
```

important is to delete `FirebaseUI`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebaseUI for Twitter and/or email, Google login, you need to include the following:

```
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Database'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Twitter'
```